# Can you surround content with a custom view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I have a bunch of code in a page that I would like to make reusable across multiple pages

```
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <SwipeView x:Name="MainSwipeView" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                   SwipeStarted="SwipeStarted" SwipeEnded="SwipeEnded" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <SwipeView.LeftItems>
            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
            <Grid x:Name="swipeContent">
  


                Where I want the rest of the content to be 
                (This means this would surround the content, similar to <ContentPresenter/> in a ControlTemplate)
  


            </Grid>
        </SwipeView>
        <StackLayout HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Label> Where the Augnito Button will be </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

I wanted to put this in a reusable component so I could use it in other pages as follows:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 . 
                 .
                 .
                 .>
    <MyReusableComponent>
         <StackLayout>

                 This is where the regular contents of a page would go

        </StackLayout>
    </MyReusableComponent>
</ContentPage>
```

I don't think I can use a `ControlTemplate` because my custom view has code behind it in a xaml.cs file to make it work, so is there another way to do this?

Comment: use a ContentView

Comment: @Jason Could you expand on that a little more? How could I do it so the stack layout I showed in the second diagram is rendered inside the SwipeContent grid in the custom view? Do you still use ContentPresenter?

Comment: A ContentView is just a XAML element that contains other elements, and you can can use it anyplace you would use any XAML element.  The docs has examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview#create-a-custom-control

Comment: @Jason But how would the nested element know that it has to render embedded inside the swipeContent Grid element that is inside the CustomView? Do you have to put a ContentPresenter inside the swipeContent Grid?

Comment: So you want a reusable control that is able to **contain** other content - ie, create your own template?

Comment: @Jason Exactly, whatever is between the <MyReusableComponent> tags would be rendered between the <Grid x:Name="swipeContent"> tags inside the reusable component.

Comment: Use Data template, n set a key to it. Use the key as static resources where ever you want to add it